# Stop Labels From Auto-fitting to Text Size in Access

Tags: ms-access, label

In Access 365, whenever I edit the text in a Label if the text is shorter than the width of the label, it auto shrinks to the size of the text.  This is very annoying.  Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Are you editing directly in label or in Properties sheet?

Comment: Why is this an issue? Do you have border or backcolor displayed on label? I don't get this behavior in Access 2010 so no idea how to prevent, sorry.